# Spring 5.3.23 Static JS files served as 'application/octet-stream' instead of 'application/javascript'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I upgraded from Spring 5.2.22-RELEASE to 5.3.23 and now I am getting the following error in Chrome when my web page tries to load static javascript files.

> Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost:10111/app/jspview/react/assets/op/app.cfd50411dd32f43695e2.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I validated that in Spring version 5.2.22-RELEASE the content type was `Content-Type: application/x-javascript`.

The file name in question has the following name

> app.cfd50411dd32f43695e2.bundle.js

The issue appears to be similar to a regression which was reported in the past https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18940 but the version is quite old.

Comment: If you can edit the servlet code you can change the header setting for .js files, although you may be able to add mime type parameters for output in the spring project configuration.